# How to change font family of app bar universally in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-appbar, flutter-theme

I want to change app bar font in my application **universally** but I did not find any appropriate answer I was looking for.
Is there any way to apply theme globally using ThemeData and theme in MaterialApp?
I don't want to apply TextStyle property like below

```
appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Title ',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'YOUR_FONT_FAMILY'),
            ),
          ),
```

If not, what is the best way to change the app bar font?

**P.S.** This is my first post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AppBarTheme`.Please find the below code

In  MaterialApp use like this,

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: ThemeData.light()
              .textTheme
              .copyWith(
                headline6: TextStyle( // instead of title use can use display as well
                  fontFamily: 'Lobster',
                ),
              )
              .apply(
                fontFamily: 'Lobster',
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

```
AppBar(
      title: Text('App bar', 
                 style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme. headline6,
             ),
    );
```

Comment: This is not working.
Also instead of creating new  AppBarTheme(), can't we just use Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copywith({}) ?

Comment: This is also possible.It Should work.Also which font family you are using and have you configured it in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Yes, it is configured in pubspec.yaml file and font family is 'Lobster'.
I am able to change it, but I want to change it universally.

Comment: Got it.Please check the updated code that i added just now in MaterialApp.Hope That works

Comment: I found that headline6 is used for primary text in app bars and dialogs. Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/headline6.html
So I configured it like this and it worked

```
appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
                textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                      headline6: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontFamily: 'Lobster',
                      ),),),
```
I did not have to use light() or dark().
This might be correct.

Comment: Cool.But this will not applied globally.You have to use it like the code that i posted

Answer (score 0):

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            headline6: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSan',
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
    ),
```

After calling Theme.of(), I got error "the receiver can be null...." and got fixed by putting the "!" in the below code

```
title: Text(
      'Title Text',
      style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme!.headline6,
    ),
```